# How to implement Solr's facet.missing=true with Lucene

Tags: lucene, facet

Solr supports returning the number of [matching documents with no facet value for the field](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/faceting.html#Faceting-Thefacet.missingParameter). How can the same be achieved with Lucene?

Example: I have 5 documents that may have values for the a field `category`

- Document 1 has `category=A`
- Document 2 has `category=A` and `category=B`
- Document 3 has `category=B` and `category=C`
- Document 4 and 5 have no `category` values

The code looks like

```
 var facetsCollector = new FacetsCollector();
 FacetsCollector.Search(_indexSearcher, new MatchAllDocsQuery(), 100, facetsCollector);
 var state = DefaultSortedSetDocValuesReaderState(_indexReader, "category_facet");
 var facets = SortedSetDocValuesFacetCounts(state, facetsCollector);
 var children = facets.GetTopChildren(100, "category_dim");
```

This gives me `LabelValues`

- Label:A, Value:2
- Label:B, Value:2
- Label:C, Value:1

How can I determine "Label:(missing), Value:2"?

Running another query `+*:* -category:*` is an obvious option. However, can it be done in a smarter way?

Answer (score 0):

Solr `facet.missing` functionality is done without any collectors by just doing this:

```
SchemaField sf = searcher.getSchema().getField(fieldName);
DocSet hasVal = searcher.getDocSet(sf.getType().getRangeQuery(null, sf, null, null, false, false));
return docs.andNotSize(hasVal);
```

which basically means - use the docset that was provided earlier by the search, get another docset by running range query which is finding only documents with missing values and then applying simple boolean operation.

Unfortunately, Lucene doesn't have built-in DocSet functionality so it would require some tricks. I could come up with something like this:

```
Query q = some Lucene query
Set<Integer> queryRes = new HashSet<>();
searcher.search(q, new CheckHits.SetCollector(queryRes));

Set<Integer> missingRes = new HashSet<>();
searcher.search(new TermRangeQuery("category", null, null, false, false), new CheckHits.SetCollector(missingRes));
missingRes.retainAll(queryRes);

System.out.println(missingRes.size());
```

HashSet retain functionality should be pretty okay in terms of speed. If further needed, this collector could be extended to store ids in somewhere more efficient way

Full example could be found [there](https://github.com/MysterionRise/information-retrieval-adventure/blob/master/lucene7/src/main/java/FacetMissingLucene.java)